# AWK: Extract lines with values that match and less than values in another file?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file called `file1` on my Linux machine with these contents:

```
ID        Time                    Energy
43 4.38665978376386365240533e-05 3.215e-02
43 4.38666558838421885677290e-05 4.788e-01
48 4.77674337753321466689890e-05 1.750e-01
48 4.77674676992522297732519e-05 3.360e-01
52 4.99184267458611271553633e-05 3.110e-01
52 4.99184755438830858337990e-05 2.000e-01
203 2.17111141925415134391192e-04 0.000e+00
203 2.17111189970080955017814e-04 1.685e-01
203 2.17111190317825032474949e-04 3.425e-01
206 2.17705422992319207490738e-04 3.197e-01
206 2.17705445825075834731174e-04 1.913e-01
245 2.54300470583329032894099e-04 2.130e-01
245 2.54300477743886715713273e-04 2.679e-02
245 2.54300499465897461830871e-04 4.887e-02
245 2.54300511632548666141052e-04 0.000e+00
245 2.54300542217183317417195e-04 0.000e+00
245 2.54300549393671508017351e-04 2.224e-01
```

and `file2`:

```
ID   Time                         Energy
43  4.38666558838421885677290e-05 4.788e-01
48  4.77674676992522297732519e-05 3.360e-01
52  4.99184267458611271553633e-05 3.110e-01
203 2.17111190317825032474949e-04 3.425e-01
206 2.17705422992319207490738e-04 3.197e-01
245 2.54300549393671508017351e-04 2.224e-01
```

I want to read `file1` and, if the energy value of a row in `file1` exists in `file2`, I should print the previous line.

The desired output from the example above is :

```
43 4.38665978376386365240533e-05 3.215e-02
48 4.77674337753321466689890e-05 1.750e-01
52 4.99184267458611271553633e-05 3.110e-01
203 2.17111189970080955017814e-04 1.685e-01
206 2.17705422992319207490738e-04 3.197e-01
245 2.54300542217183317417195e-04 0.000e+00
```

The question is: In same ID number, when the energy value of a row in file1 exists in file2, print the row before this one. can anyone kown how to do this by awk?
I have tried code :

```
gawk '
NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next }
{
    split(a[FNR],flds,FS,seps)
    if(flds[1]=$1 && flds[2] <=$2)
  print flds}' file1 file2 > flie3
```

Then using sort | uniq to remove the repeated lines with same id.

Time value is incremental in all files, and once the line with same energy value as file2 is in the first line within same ID number, then only choose this line. like **52 4.99184267458611271553633e-05 3.110e-01**

Comment: Can the IDs be repeated in `file2` or will there always be one, unique value per id?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/583549/edit) your post to tell us what you already tried, and where you encountered problems?

Comment: Why is the line `52 4.99184267458611271553633e-05 3.110e-01` in your desired output? Don't you want to print the _previous_ line?

Comment: Sorry I am not so skillful to use this tool, I re-edit my question just now. Within the same ID number, in file1, line with same energy value as file2 is just in the first line, then we just choose this first line as output.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
  NR==FNR{ if (FNR>1)a[$1]=$3; next } # file2: save ID,Energy value in array `a`
  $1 in a{                            # file1: if ID is present in array
     if (a[$1] != $3){                # if it is not the same Energy value...
       prev=$0                        # save previous line
     }
     else {                           # it is the same Energy value...
       print (prev=="") ? $0 : prev   # print previous line if saved or current line
       prev=""                        # reset previous line
     }
  }
' file2 file1 > file3
```

Output:

```
43 4.38665978376386365240533e-05 3.215e-02
48 4.77674337753321466689890e-05 1.750e-01
52 4.99184267458611271553633e-05 3.110e-01
203 2.17111189970080955017814e-04 1.685e-01
206 2.17705422992319207490738e-04 3.197e-01
245 2.54300542217183317417195e-04 0.000e+00
```

Comment: Thank you. The second column means time and is  incremental from top to bottom.  For example 52  4.99184267458611271553633e-05 3.110e-01 in file2 is located in the first row w.s.t the ID of 52, before it is rows of ID 48. So I just need to extract the first row: 52  4.99184267458611271553633e-05 3.110e-01 as output. In another word, it is not only printing previous line. Output needs to include all the ID value in file1, but only one row per ID.

Comment: Ah, so it's take the previous line of `file1` with the same ID if it exists. If not, then just take the line. And then you don't need my second command with `sort`, right?

Comment: Yes,thank you very much. I should change if (FNR>1) to if(FNR>=1),otherwise, the first line of ID 43 will be lost.

Comment: I added it to skip the header line in `file2`. You can remove the `if (FNR>1)` if you don't need it (removing it is the same as `if (FNR>=1)`).

Comment: really thank you, it works well. And I wonder If I added extral column, for example, called location, which has the same usage as Energy. can I just use if (FNR>1)a[$1]=$3;b[$1]=$4; next }  $1 in a{......}?like this format, saving energy and location in two different array?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just make sure you use brackets around both array assignments `if (FNR>1){a...;b...} next`, I left them since it was only one assignment.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!